Selenium checking stale did not work for chrome driver version 126
Selenium checking stale did not work for chrome driver version 126:
public boolean isElementStale(WebElement element) {
        try {
            element.isEnabled();
            return false;
        } catch (StaleElementReferenceException e) {
            return true;
        }
    }

It works for chrome driver older version 112.
For the new version 126, it throws
org.openqa.selenium.NoSuchElementException: no such element: element not found

How to check if an element becomes stale?

there is the stalenessOf expected condition:  https://www.selenium.dev/selenium/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/support/ui/ExpectedConditions.html#stalenessOf(org.openqa.selenium.WebElement)  But if the element is not found and was in the past, it's basically the same thing so you could catch NoSuchElementException and return true as well.
